# how to change backgrounnd color in react day picker conditionally

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

hello guys I have an array of dates which I am getting from backend and and pass that array to React Day Picker. which shows all the date in calender as selected with the default blue color.
Now what I want is that when user clicks on that dates on the calender it should change the background color to orange if the user clicks that is present in the array of dates.

I tried to put condition in modifiersStyles but it seems not working.

here is my code.

```
<DayPicker
                mode="single"                  
                selected={onlyDates}
                onDayClick={(event) => {
                  handleDateChange(event);
                  setClickedDate(event)  ;
              }}
                formatters={{
                  formatWeekdayName: (day) => day?.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'short' }),
                  }}
                  modifiersStyles={{
                    
                    selected: {
                      backgroundColor: onlyDates.includes(clickedDate) ? 'red' : 'gray',
                      color: 'white',
                    },
                    today: {
                      color: 'white',
                      backgroundColor: '#0000ff',
                    },
                  }} 
              />
```

here onDayClick I am setting the date to a state called clickedDate and than in checking in modifierStyles that the clickedDate is present in the onlyDates array. and change the color based on that.

[image]

below I have given the image of calender where all gray colors date are in the onlyDates array.